# apollo-link-state update cache and return async resolver

Tags: asynchronous, hyperlink, state, apollo, resolver

How to update cache and return async resolver with apollo-link-state.

Example:

```
import {
    LOGIN_FORM_QC as query
} from '../../querys'

import axios from 'axios'
import axiosError from '../axiosError'
import {URL} from '../../config'

const newState = (cache, object) => {
    const state = cache.readQuery({query})
    const data = {
        ...state,
        ...{loginForm: {
            ...state.loginForm,
            ...object
        }}
    }
    cache.writeQuery({query, data})
    return null
}

export default (_, input, {cache}) => {
    newState(cache, {loading: true, error: null}) //<-- this is not updating

    const state = cache.readQuery({query})
    const {uid, password} = state.loginForm

    return axios.post(`${URL}/login`, {uid, password})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            console.log(res.message)
        })
        .catch(err => newState(cache, {
            error: axiosError(err),
            loading: false
        }))
}
```

Basically, I want to set loading: true, and then execute promise. And promise will update state again.
As I understand, to update state I need to do return first. How to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

As of **22.03.2018**:

This can't be done properly. To fix this issue you have to import apollo client and call writeQuery on it. Then it works.

GitHub issue tread: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/issues/200